# Calendar months wrong

Tags: java

I try to set a simple date certain years after with calendar:

String date is a parameter of this metod.

```
     SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");

    String[] DateTimeParts = date.split(" ");
    String dt = DateTimeParts[0];
    String[] dateParts = dt.split("-");
    int d = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[2]);


    int y = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[0]);
    int m = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[1]);




    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    calendar.set(y, m-1, d);
    calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, years);


    return format.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

My problem is that the date return is otherwise fine, but the month number is totally wrong, and seems to be getting bigger on each run! What I'm missing?

Comment: What do you mean "on each run"? And what inputs are you providing?

Comment: You are using lower case `m`, which IIRC is for minutes.  `M` (upper case) is for months.  Try "dd.MM.yyyy".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using lowercase "m" for month, when you should be using uppercase "M", i.e

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

lowercase "m" is used to format minutes - see the java API for [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use uppercase for month, otherwise you get minutes =)
try:

```
dd.MM.yyyy
```

More: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Other Answers are correct but outdated.

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "23.01.2017" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu" ) 
)
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu" );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "23.01.2017" , f ); // January 23, 2017.
```

And going the other direction. Note that unlike the legacy classes, the java.time class have sane month numbering, 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2017 , 1 , 23 ); January 23, 2017.
String output = localDate.format( f );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).