# Java - Formating date in a right way and inserting it into mysql db

Tags: java, mysql, date

Ok, I have a form with a date picker that I made which brings the input value in a dd-mm-yyyy format.

I am checking the output on every step but I'm stuck on a first. So part of the code like this.

**Servlet controller:**

```
Pacijent pacijent = new Pacijent();
try {
    Date datum = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").parse(request.getParameter("datum"));
    pacijent.setDatum(datum);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
out.println(pacijent.getDatum());
//not important part of a code ...
//dao.addPacijent(pacijent);
```

**Pacijent class:**

```
public class Pacijent {
    private int id;
    private String ime;
    private String prezime;
    private Date datum;
    private String adresa;
    // Getters and Setters...
}
```

**Insert function in PacijentDao class**

```
public void addPacijent(Pacijent pacijent) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pacijent (ime, prezime, datum, adresa) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, pacijent.getIme());
        ps.setString(2, pacijent.getPrezime());
        ps.setDate(3, (Date) pacijent.getDatum());
        ps.setString(4, pacijent.getAdresa());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And after I click submit button it outputs me date like this **Wed Jan 18 00:04:00 CET 2017**. I need help to parse it in a way that mysql accepts it. Datum field in database is Date format.

Thanks

Comment: Format should be `"dd-MM-yyyy"`. Lowercase `mm` means *minute*, uppercase means *month*.

Comment: Duplicate of [Calendar months wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7596760/5221149)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ps.setDate(); asks for a java.sql.Date  which is different from java.util.Date

You can try to use

```
ps.setDate("a", new java.sql.Date(pacijent.getDatum().getTime()));
 or use a timestamp 
ps.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(pacijent.getDatum().getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've managed to find a way to do this. Here is the correct code.
**Servlet controller:**

```
Pacijent pacijent = new Pacijent();
try {
   Date dop = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(request.getParameter("datum"));
        pacijent.setDatum(dop);
} catch(ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
out.println(pacijent.getDatum());
//not important part of a code ...
//dao.addPacijent(pacijent);
```

**Insert function in PacijentDao class**

```
public void addPacijent(Pacijent pacijent) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pacijent (ime, prezime, datum, adresa) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, pacijent.getIme());
        ps.setString(2, pacijent.getPrezime());
        ps.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(pacijent.getDatum().getTime()));
        ps.setString(4, pacijent.getAdresa());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```